# Python3 Speedtest is suddenly reporting much slower speeds

Tags: python, speed-test

I built an Internet Monitor, now posted on Instructables (https://www.instructables.com/The-Internet-Monitor/). It works well, reporting on speedtest results every 30 minutes. It uses the standard python approach reported in the Speedtest-CLI Python API wiki (https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/wiki). I was getting an average of 320 MBps download speed through my cable internet carrier.

Last weekend, I had gigabit fiber internet installed. The Ookla speedtests on the new fiber modem router showed 1332 MBps download. I was thrilled. I have an Eero Pro 6E Gigabit mesh router system, so I configured the new fiber modem router for passthrough to my mesh system. My laptop directly connected to my mesh router reported 980 MBps download. Slight losses, but still acceptable.

However, my Internet Monitor dropped speed reporting to less than 130MBps, with a direct connection to the mesh router. I tried it directly connected to the fiber router with no change - downloads reported less than 130MBps.

The Internet Monitor is run by a Raspberry Pi 4B, with gigabit ethernet. I changed cables, looked at every connection, and the results were the same. So I then went through and updated all the software and libraries on the Pi and finally uninstalled Speedtest. I then reinstalled it using the direct link to the Github repository. Nothing changed!  Still getting the less than 130MBps on the monitor. My laptop on WiFi using the Ookla test shows download speeds exceeding 500MBps.

I'm at a loss on what has caused the problem. Any ideas? Is there a problem with Speedtest-CLI?

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is only for questions about writing code, asked with enough details to permit a canonical answer (where others, not just you, can test whether an answer is correct -- without this property one lacks a [MRE]). A question tied to numerous hidden variables (your ISP's upstreams, router behavior, etc etc) that aren't necessarily code-related at all isn't suitable here.

Comment: This is probably not whats wrong but maybe your PI is connecting via WiFi despite being plugged into the ethernet directly and that is causing the slower speed. You should try another stack website about networking